# Symfony 6.2 api response return empty data

Tags: api, symfony, response, httpresponse

I have custom authenticator for API requests and when i was try do any request i got empty data in response.

**security.yaml**

```xml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)

    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            lazy: true
            pattern: ^/api/
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\MyApiAuthenticator
```

**MyApiAuthenticator**

```php
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    // debug just help me trace in log file
    $this->logger->debug(__CLASS__.'::'.__FUNCTION__, ['$request' => $request, 'token' => $token, '$firewallName' => $firewallName]);
        
    // nothing to do
    return new Response(
        json_encode(['message' => 'hello world']),
        200,
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8']
    );
}
```

An interesting thing if you remove the **Content-Type** from the header, the response **Content-Type** will change to text/html.

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:41493
Date: Wed, 03 May 2023 08:16:24 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Date: Wed, 03 May 2023 08:16:24 GMT
X-Debug-Token: 1f3805
X-Debug-Token-Link: http://127.0.0.1:41493/_profiler/1f3805
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Expires: Wed, 03 May 2023 08:16:24 GMT
```

**Update**: everything is working fine and as expected, if dont look at in browser developer tools network tab
[image]

Any one know why is happen?